# Plasmar idea en código. ¿Qué es qué y cómo se intercomunican?

Tags: python-3.x, poo

Entiendo que mi pregunta es muy ambigua y que puede tener muchas respuestas diferentes.

Estoy recién empezando a enfrentarme a la programación orientada a objeto y no es fácil, jaja. Pero uno de los problemas que se me plantean por mi inexperiencia es saber cómo plasmar una idea en líneas de código que tengan sentido y que se intercomuniquen entre sí de la forma que debería, es decir, llevar la realidad a un lenguaje de programación.

Os comento: estoy intentando plasmar en python un juego de rol basado en dados y me encuentro con la duda de que realmente no sé qué debería ser una clase, qué debería ser un método o qué debería ser una variable, etc.

¿Cómo aprender eso o cómo enfocarme para ir desarrollándolo es lo que me inquieta? Aprendo por mi cuenta, así que solo tengo la ayuda del foro y de vosotros, por cierto gracias, para resolver estos temas, que pienso, deberían ser explicados por un profesor, jaja, así que muchas gracias de antemano.

Por si no os he aburrido ya con tanta cháchara, os explico un poco de qué va el juego, lo que más o menos pienso que debo hacer y lo que llevo hecho.

**Como se juega**

- De 1 a X Jugadores.
- Hay dos set de 7 dados, uno de mazmorra y otro de compañeros.
- El set de mazmorra contiene: dragon: rojo, ghoul: azul, goblin: verde, esqueleto: blanco, cofre: púrpura y poción: amarillo.
- El set de compañeros contiene: campeón: amarillo, mago: azul, guerrero: verde, templario: blanco, ladrón: morado y pergamino: marrón.
- Un dado del jugador en curso, es decir, un dado del set grupos, puede vencer a cualquier cantidad de dados del set mazmorra del mismo color. Por lo tanto, un guerrero puede vencer a cualquier cantidad de goblin (ambos son verdes). Un mago, a cualquier cantidad de ghoul (ambos son azul).
- Un dado del set de grupo, solo puede vencer a un dado, enemigo, del set mazmorra de un color diferente. Por lo tanto, el ladrón, solo puede matar a un goblin o a un esqueleto.
- El campeón puede vencer a cualquier cantidad de dados enemigos de un mismo color, es decir, un campeón puede vencer a todos los globlins o a todos los esqueletos o a todos los ghouls, pero solo a u grupo de ellos.
- El ladrón y el campeón pueden abrir, ambos, cualquier número de cofres.
- Cada cofre, te da un tesoro. Los tesoros pueden ser otros compañeros de grupo u objetos con habilidades especiales. Si necesitáis más información sobre los objetos, la proveo.
- Si sale una cara de dragón, esta se almacena en "la guarida del dragón" y en el momento en el que haya 3 o más dados en la guardia del dragón, el dragón emerge y el grupo debe vencerlo para poder enfrentarse a los otros monstruos que hayan salido en la misma tirada o reclamar los tesoros. Vencer al dragón te provee un punto de experiencia y un tesoro.
- Hay cartas especiales, los héroes, que encarnan tu avatar en la partida. Cada héroe tiene una habilidad especial, que podrá utilizar en cualquier momento de la partida indefinidas veces, siempre que le sea posible. Por ejemplo, poder usar los guerreros como magos y los magos como guerrero, entre otras habilidades.
- Los héroes, además, tienen una habilidad especial que podrán usar una única vez por bajada a la mazmorra.
- Los héroes ganan puntos de experiencia y cuando acumulan 5 evolucionan y sus efectos cambian.
- Bajar un nivel de la guarida del dragón te proporciona 1 punto de exp. Por lo tanto, bajar 4 niveles, te proporciona 4 puntos y bajar 7 niveles, 7 puntos.
- Para poder conseguir los puntos de experiencia, así como los tesoros que hayas ido adquiriendo, deberás salir vivo de la mazmorra. Para ello, debes limpiar el nivel en el que estés y decidir irte. Si mueres, pierdes todo y empiezas de nuevo en el siguiente turno.
- El grupo de compañeros se crea al inicio, tirándo los 7 dados.
- Cada nivel de la mazmorra añade un nuevo dado de enemigo. En el nivel 1 hay 1 dado de enemigo, en el nivel 6 hay 6 dados.
- Cada participante baja a la mazmorra 3 veces, una vez cada uno.
- Gana el participante que más puntos de experiencia haya conseguido o que llegue directamente al nivel 10 de la guarida y limpie la zona.
- El pergamino te permite tirar cualquier número de dados en el terreno, ya sea de enemigos o compañeros o incluso ambos a la vez.

Perdonar el tostón de párrafos. Eso es más o menos lo que hace el juego. Y esto es lo que yo llevo:

```py
from random import choices

class Monstruos:
    def __init__(self):
        self.posibilidades = [
            {"pocima"    : "naranja"},
            {"goblin"    : "verde"},
            {"ghoul"     : "azul"},
            {"esqueleto" : "blanco"},
            {"Cofre"     : "morado"},
            {"dragón"    : "rojo"}
        ]
        self.guarida_dragon = []
    def crear_grupo_enemigo(self, tamano):
        self.grupo_enemigo = choices(self.posibilidades, weights=[2,2,2,2,1,1], k=tamano)
        self.dragones_enemigos()

    def dragones_enemigos(self):
        [self.guarida_dragon.append(dragon) for dragon in self.grupo_enemigo if dragon == {"dragón": "rojo"}]
        self.purgar_dragon()

    def purgar_dragon(self):
        if self.grupo_enemigo.count({"dragón": "rojo"}) > 0:
            for i in range(self.grupo_enemigo.count({"dragón": "rojo"})):
                self.grupo_enemigo.remove({"dragón": "rojo"})
        []
        [self.guarida_dragon.remove({"dragón": "rojo"})for i in range(self.guarida_dragon.count({"dragón": "rojo"}))]


class Grupo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.posibilidades = [
            {"pergamino": "marrón"},
            {"guerrero" : "verde"},
            {"mago"     : "azul"},
            {"templario": "blanco"},
            {"ladrón"   : "morado"},
            {"campeón"  : "amarillo"}
        ]

    def crear_grupo_companero(self):
        self.grupo_companeros = choices(self.posibilidades, weights=[1,2,2,2,2,1],k=7)
```

Comment: tu duda entonces esta basada en como identificar de tu problema: ¿qué es una clase, objeto y variable?

Comment: La pregunta en si parece muy amplia, pues por un lado agregas un fragmento de código del cual no indicas que dudas tienes al respecto y por otro lado expones dudas acerca de la teoría, que parecen entonces 2 intenciones en la misma publicación, te sugiero leer [ask]

Comment: Perdonar si no me he expresado bien, mi duda, únicamente, es cómo expresar en código el juego. Es decir, cómo debería enfocar toda la información que he proporcionado para plasmarla en un código funcional.

Sí, es una pregunta muy amplia, dado que se basa en todo lo referente a la programación orientada a objeto.

La pregunta tal cual, es si me podéis guiar un poco, para ir armando el código

Comment: me temo que así la pregunta esta fuera del alcance de [ask], pues las dudas aquí vertidas deberían ser sobre el código que llevas, ¿por qué?, bueno pues por que cada usuario que lea esta pregunta con base en su propia experiencia te dará una respuesta distinta, de mejor o menor calidad pero no terminarás de recibir una única respuesta, te sugiero checar el [tour] para comprender mejor la plataforma

Comment: He añadido más información al comentario.

Entiendo que es una pregunta muy espesa, y como dices la respuesta variará según la persona, pero creo que al menos así puedo ir tomando idea de cómo hacerlo.

Le hecho un vistazo al link. Muchas gracias ^^

Comment: el problema es que las preguntas basadas en opiniones no son bien recibidas en la comunidad precisamente por lo amplias que son y generalmente terminan cerradas, pero oye tienes suficiente reputación para entrar al [chat] y seguro ahí si es bien recibida tu pregunta

Comment: Ni idea de que había un chat... jajaja. Ni tampoco de qué es eso de la reputación, pero gracias por la información. Iré a echarle un vistazo al chat y a que me llamen pesado! jajaja.

Gracias!